# I want to test this Python file Management code using unit test module, but I'm getting errors

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

The python script is using os to walk on a directory and it is assessing to see if any file is inside the folder for ten or more seconds, if there is a file that meets this condition, three things happen:

- the event is logged with a timestamp into a log file
- A file is created inside an "expired" folder, which is any file that meets the condition in the format: {log_timestamp}_{Path(file_path).stem}.txt which contains in its contents, the file path of
- The file is recorded in the format (full-file-path, name-of-file-in-expired_Folder) inside a metadata.txt file

In the following iterations (every 60 seconds) after the first, a delete-files function runs where the directory is os.walk()-ed to see if there is a file that doesn't exist from the last iteration, if it doesn't, the corresponding file in the expired folder is deleted and the line in 'metadata.txt' that corresponds to the file that was deleted/moved out of the directory.

fileCheck.py:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import argparse
import shutil

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='directory tree & file logging')
    parser.add_argument("--directory", "-d", required=True, type=str, default='.',
                        dest="dirToW", help="directory to watch, specify path")
    parser.add_argument("--log-file", "-lf", required=True, type=str, default='.',
                        dest="lf", help="log file location with full path")
    parser.add_argument("--interval", "-i", type=int, default=60, dest="intl",
                        help="interval for periodic checks (in seconds)")
    parser.add_argument("--exclude-file", "-ef", type=str, dest="excl_file",
                        help="list of files to exclude from fileCheck")
    parser.add_argument("--expired-folder", "-exp", type=str, required=True, dest="exp_folder",
                        help="folder to move expired files to")
    parser.add_argument("--metadata-file", "-meta", type=str, required=True, dest="meta_file",
                        help="metadata file to help delete expired files")

    return parser.parse_args()

def configure_logging(log_file_path):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_path, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        filemode='a+')

    # Add a stream handler to display log messages to the console
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(console_handler)

def read_exclude_list(exclude_file):
    exclude_list = set()
    if exclude_file:
        try:
            with open(exclude_file, 'r') as file:
                # Read full file paths and resolve them
                exclude_list.update(Path(line.strip()).resolve() for line in file)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading exclude file: {e}")
    return exclude_list

def check_existing_files(checked_files, directory_to_watch, log_file_path, exclusion_list, exp_folder, meta_file):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Before checking files:", checked_files)
    directory_to_watch_path = Path(directory_to_watch).resolve()

    # Set to store files in directory
    current_files = set()
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_watch_path):
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print("Processing file:", file_path)
            current_files.add(file_path)

            try:
                file_creation_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file_path))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue

            time_difference = current_time - file_creation_time
            full_path = Path(file_path).resolve()
            if (int(time_difference.total_seconds()) > 10 and full_path not in checked_files and full_path not in exclusion_list):
                log_msg = f"File '{full_path}' has been in the directory for more than ten seconds."
                logging.info(log_msg)
                checked_files.add(full_path)  # Add full path to checked_files
                copy_to_expired_folder(full_path, exp_folder, meta_file)
                log_created_file(full_path, log_file_path)

            print("After checking files:", checked_files)

    return checked_files

def log_created_file(file_path, lf):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    log_message = f"File {file_path} added at {current_time}"
    logging.info(log_message)

def copy_to_expired_folder(file_path, exp_folder, meta_file):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    log_timestamp = current_time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.%f")

    try:
        # Copy the file to the expired files folder
        expired_file_path = Path(exp_folder) / f"{log_timestamp}_{Path(file_path).stem}.txt"
        with open(expired_file_path, 'w') as expired_file:
            expired_file.write(str(file_path) + '\n')

        # Write to metadata file
        with open(meta_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"{Path(expired_file_path).name}, {file_path}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error copying file: {e}")

def delete_files(directory_to_watch, exp_folder, meta_file):
    checked_files = set()
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_watch):
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            checked_files.add(file_path)

    expired_files = os.listdir(exp_folder)
    for expired_file in expired_files:
        expired_file_path = os.path.join(exp_folder, expired_file)
        if os.path.isfile(expired_file_path):
            # Read the content of the expired file
            with open(expired_file_path, 'r') as f:
                expired_content = f.read().strip()

            # Check if the expired content (full path) is not in the checked_files (full path of dirToW files)
            if expired_content not in checked_files:
                os.remove(expired_file_path)
                logging.info(f"Deleted expired file: {expired_file_path}")

                with open(meta_file, 'r') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()
                with open(meta_file, 'w') as f:
                    for line in lines:
                        if expired_file in line:
                            continue
                        f.write(line)
def main():
    args = parse_arguments()

    # Configure logging, logs are appended to a file
    configure_logging(args.lf)

    # Initial check for existing files
    checked_files = set()
    exclude_list = read_exclude_list(args.excl_file)
    checked_files = check_existing_files(checked_files, args.dirToW, args.lf, exclude_list, args.exp_folder, args.meta_file)
    print(f"Log file path: {args.lf}")

    try:
        while True:
            # Periodic check, specify in argument, default 60 seconds
            time.sleep(args.intl)
            exclude_list = read_exclude_list(args.excl_file)
            checked_files = check_existing_files(checked_files, args.dirToW, args.lf, exclude_list, args.exp_folder, args.meta_file)
            delete_files(args.dirToW, args.exp_folder, args.meta_file)
            print("another loop")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

fileCheck_test.py:

```
import unittest
import os
import logging
import datetime
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
from unittest.mock import patch
from fileCheck import *

class TestScript(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Create a single temporary directory for all tests
        cls.test_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir='/home/semir-testing/floor/test-env/')

    def setUp(self):
        # Create mock directory within the single temporary directory
        self.mock_dir = os.path.join(self.test_dir, "mock_Dir")
        if not os.path.exists(self.mock_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.mock_dir)

        self.another_dir = os.path.join(self.mock_dir, "anotherDir")
        if not os.path.exists(self.another_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.another_dir)

        # Create the expired folder
        self.expired_folder = os.path.join(self.test_dir, "expired")
        if not os.path.exists(self.expired_folder):
            os.makedirs(self.expired_folder)

        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        creation_time = current_time - datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)  # 20 seconds ago
        with open(os.path.join(self.mock_dir, "file1"), "w") as f:
            f.write("content1\n")

            os.utime(f.name, (creation_time.timestamp(), creation_time.timestamp()))
        with open(os.path.join(self.mock_dir, "file2"), "w") as f:
            f.write("content2\n")

            os.utime(f.name, (creation_time.timestamp(), creation_time.timestamp()))
        with open(os.path.join(self.another_dir, "file3.txt"), "w") as f:
            f.write("content3\n")
            os.utime(f.name, (creation_time.timestamp(), creation_time.timestamp()))

        # Create the exclude file
        self.exclude_file = os.path.join(self.test_dir, "exclude.txt")
        with open(self.exclude_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(os.path.join(self.mock_dir, "file1\n"))

        # Create the metadata file
        self.meta_file = os.path.join(self.test_dir, "metadata.txt")

        # Create the log file
        self.log_file = os.path.join(self.test_dir, "test.log")
        logging.basicConfig(filename=self.log_file, level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', filemode='a+')

        # Configure logging for the tests
        configure_logging(self.log_file)

    def test_read_exclude_list(self):
        exclude_file = os.path.join(self.test_dir, 'exclude.txt')
        with open(exclude_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join([os.path.join(self.mock_dir, 'another_Dir', 'file3.txt')]))

        exclude_list = read_exclude_list(exclude_file)

        self.assertEqual(len(exclude_list), 1)
        self.assertIn(Path(os.path.join(self.mock_dir, 'another_Dir', 'file3.txt')), exclude_list)

    def test_check_existing_files(self):
        # Mock the logging functions
        with patch('fileCheck.logging') as mock_logging:
            # Set the current time to 10 seconds ago
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

            # Set up exclude list
            exclude_list = set()

            # Call the function
            checked_files = set()
            checked_files = check_existing_files(checked_files, self.test_dir, 'test.log', exclude_list, self.expired_folder, self.meta_file)

            # Check if the files were copied correctly
            for root, _, files in os.walk(self.mock_dir):
                for test_file in files:
                    if os.path.join(root, test_file) not in exclude_list:
                        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.expired_folder, f"{test_file}.txt")))

    def test_copy_to_expired_folder(self):
        # Set up test data
        file_path = os.path.join(self.mock_dir, "file1")
        exp_folder = self.expired_folder
        meta_file = self.meta_file

        # Call the function
        copy_to_expired_folder(file_path, exp_folder, meta_file)

        # Check if the file was copied and metadata was written
        log_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.%f")
        expected_expired_file_path = os.path.join(exp_folder, f"{log_timestamp}_file1.txt")
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(expected_expired_file_path))

        # Check if metadata was written
        with open(meta_file, 'r') as f:
            metadata_content = f.read()
        self.assertIn(f"{log_timestamp}_file1.txt, {file_path}", metadata_content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The main issue I'm having is that the files created in the setUp method are the three events described above aren't taking place when running the test.

Errors in test script:

```
Before checking files: set()
Processing file: /home/semir-testing/floor/test-env/tmpfggyv_pv/mock_Dir/file2
After checking files: set()
Processing file: /home/semir-testing/floor/test-env/tmpfggyv_pv/mock_Dir/file1
After checking files: set()
Processing file: /home/semir-testing/floor/test-env/tmpfggyv_pv/mock_Dir/anotherDir/file3.txt
After checking files: set()
Checked Files (After): set()
FF.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_check_existing_files (__main__.TestScript)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/semir-testing/floor/fileCheck_test.py", line 90, in test_check_existing_files
    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.expired_folder, f"{test_file}.txt")))
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: test_copy_to_expired_folder (__main__.TestScript)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/semir-testing/floor/fileCheck_test.py", line 105, in test_copy_to_expired_folder
    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(expected_expired_file_path))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.010s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Even though I'm not testing the logging currently, the logging works fine, but that's not an issue I'm worried about at the moment. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As a first step in debugging this issue, add a print or log message that displays the exact filename that was not found.  (i.e. maybe you made a silly mistake and the test is looking for `filename.txt.txt`)

Comment: I have added debugging and if you look on the error log, you can see the files being processed and each file being processed, I should note that only file1 is being processed correctly, the rest aren't despite the condition being met